# looking for a sample swing project

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, user-interface

I am trying to build a complex GUI with Swing and would like to ask whether someone has a good project in mind that follows the best practices around for building complex GUIs. I would love to have a look at the source code to get some ideas about the overall structure (especially on how the MVC is implemented)
thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this isn't a question suited for this site; it's overly broad and not a specific programming question. Please see the FAQ and perhaps look around at other questions.

Comment: -1 Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for an explanation about what kinds of questions are appropriate here.

Comment: thought stackoverflow is a place for any programming related question? this guy made a good question, some people made a valid answer, and I thank for them, brain roach and code-guru are unbelievable person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting how this question got downvoted, while similar questions were upvoted... Check these (and maybe the next time do some research, this was already asked a few times...)

[Up-to-date Swing MVC example + Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330385/up-to-date-swing-mvc-example-question)

[How to organize a Swing GUI application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269851/how-to-organize-a-swing-gui-application)

[What's a good example of a Java Swing application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234428/whats-a-good-example-of-a-java-swing-application)

Comment: some interesting things in there, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you take a look at the application called SwingSet3. It is developed for showing some of the Swing widgets with source code included. You can also find the entire application source code if you want to see how it is organized.

Comment: I will keep a reference of this application, there are some things I can copy instead of reimplementing : ) thanks.